# how to check an array for inputs that are outside a condition more then once

Tags: python-3.x

In my code I have commented out the part that I cannot do. 
What would be the logic to check if there was a value inputted that was outside the acceptable range of 36 - 37.5 more then twice for a baby it would print 'call a doctor'

at the moment I cant do the value out of acceptable range more then twice part.

```py
import numpy as np

temps_array = [i for i in range(8)]

for x in range(0, 8):
    temp = float(input('Enter the temperature of the baby '))
    if temp < 36.0:
        print('The baby is too cold')
        temps_array[x] = temp
    elif temp > 37.5:
        print('The baby is too hot')
        temps_array[x] = temp
    else:
        print('The babies temperature is within range')
        temps_array[x] = temp

difference = np.max(temps_array) - np.min(temps_array)


if difference > 1:
    print('Because the difference in temperature for your baby is 
        greater then 1 you need to - Call a doc')
# elif: or the baby has had a temperature outside the range more then twice
# print('call a doctor')
else:
    print('Your baby is doing well')
```

Answer (score 1):

You add a counter, which you increment if the temperature is out of range:

```
import numpy as np

temps_array = [i for i in range(8)]

# Create the counter
out_of_range_count = 0

for x in range(0, 8):
    temp = float(input('Enter the temperature of the baby '))
    if temp < 36.0:
        print('The baby is too cold')
        temps_array[x] = temp
        out_of_range_count += 1      # Increment the counter if out of range
    elif temp > 37.5:
        print('The baby is too hot')
        temps_array[x] = temp
        out_of_range_count += 1      # Increment it here too
    else:
        print('The babies temperature is within range')
        temps_array[x] = temp

difference = np.max(temps_array) - np.min(temps_array)


if difference > 1:
    print('Because the difference in temperature for your baby is greater then 1 you need to - Call a doc')
elif out_of_range_count >= 2:     # Check if it was out of range multiple times
    print('call a doctor')
else:
    print('Your baby is doing well')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `numpy`:

```py
>>> x
[35.0, 36.6, 37.7, 32.3, 36.5, 36.9, 36.7, 38.0]
>>> any(np.logical_or(np.array(x)<36, np.array(x)>37.5))
True
```